# Onvif - get magnification factor

Tags: c++, camera, wsdl, onvif

I'm implementing in C++ an ONVIF client in order to drive Onvif cameras.

I need to get the magnification factor (x1 in zoom min, x200 in zoom max for example), but so far I only manage to get PTZ values (pan, tilt & zoom in percentage). It's easy to transform pan and tilt from % to degrees but I don't know how to compute the magnification factor.

I've looked at the WSDL files but I don't see what I need.

I would be fine with:

- either a service telling me directly the magnification factor (for instance x64)
- the currently field of view of the lens (for instance 12°). I can easily get the max field of view and compute the magnification factor then:

  magnification_factor = current_field_of_view / field_of_view_max
- the min & max fields of view of the camera:

  current_field_of_view = min_field_of_view + (max_field_of_view - min_field_of_view)*(1-zoom)
  magnification_factor = current_field_of_view / field_of_view_max

But I don't see any of it in the interface.

Can someone help?

[edit : solution found]

I've asked the user to set max value of the magnification which is always available in the specs. Then I compute the current magnification with the formula :

```
current_mag = 1 + current_zoom * (max_mag - 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zoom factor is a value between a min and max specified by each device in ZoomLimits data in the PTZ service. Unfortunately this does not have to represent any real world value and is often between 0.0 and 1.0.

What you could do is in the device WSDL, request GetDeviceInformation and if you know the actual zoom capabilities in real values you could store them and compare against the model/manufacturer in your application.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less what I've done. I've asked the user to set max value of the magnification which is always available in the specs. Then I compute the current magnification with the formula : current_mag = 1 + current_zoom * (max_mag - 1)